# Coldfusion taking list of dates and putting them in correct date order

Tags: coldfusion

Grabbing delimited dates from database and adding new ones to the list, then want to put all dates in correct order of  the date.

```
<cfparam default="" name="newDates">
<cfloop index="tm" from="#form.arrive#" to="#form.depart#" step="#createTimespan(1,0,0,0)#">    

<cfset newDates = newDates & '#dateFormat( tm, "mm/dd/yyyy" )#,'>

</cfloop>
<cfset penddate = '#pmonthlist#, #newDates#'>
```

How Can I take the results of this.

7/15/2012,7/16/2012,7/17/2012,7/18/2012,7/19/2012,7/20/2012,7/21/2012,9/21/2012,9/22/2012,9/28/2012,9/29/2012, 04/01/2012,04/02/2012,04/03/2012,04/04/2012,04/05/2012,04/06/2012,04/07/2012,

And make it into the correct date order like this. (this is the results I want)

04/01/2012,04/02/2012,04/03/2012,04/04/2012,04/05/2012,04/06/2012,04/07/2012,7/15/2012,7/16/2012,7/17/2012,7/18/2012,7/19/2012,7/20/2012,7/21/2012,9/21/2012,9/22/2012,9/28/2012,9/29/2012

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**UPDATE:** Solution #0 - just sort them using `arraySort(dates, 'numeric')`  (doesn't work in Railo), see: http://www.cfgears.com/index.cfm/2010/10/7/Using-an-array-to-sort-dates

Solution #1 - sort an array of dates

1. Turn the list of `dates` into an array using `ListToArray()`
2. loop through the array and `DateFormat()` them as `YYYYMMDD`
3. `ArraySort(dates, 'numeric')`
4. loop through the dates again and `DateFormat()` them back to `M/D/YYYY`
5. `ArrayToList()`

Solution #2 - use Query of Queries

1. if you have a query object with records of dates, skip to step 2.
2. set myQuery as QueryNew('MyDate','Date')
3. loop through the dates, and add them into the query using `QueryAddRow()` and `QuerySetCell()`
4. use Query of Queries: `SELECT MyDate FROM myQuery ORDER BY MyDate`
5. `ValueList(myQuery.myDate)`

Solution #3 - use Java

1. turn list of dates into an array
2. loop through the array, use `javacast` to cast each date as `java.util.Date`
3. invoke `sort()` in `java.util.Collections` on the array

Solution #4 - use `DateCompare()`

1. turn list of dates into an array
2. write your own sorting algorithm (insertion sort? bubble sort?), using `DateCompare()` to compare dates.

Solution #5 - use DB temp table

1. insert into a temp table
2. select them out using `ORDER BY`

Comment: CF is actually smart enough to just use arraySort() on dates... http://www.cfgears.com/index.cfm/2010/10/7/Using-an-array-to-sort-dates but I'd still prefer my solution #1 because it relies less on CF to be smart enough to sort them as date, not string.

Comment: It looks like the cfgears site is down.  If you still have access to the code, could you update with maybe a github gist?

Comment: @jinglesthula it's just `arraySort(dates, 'numeric')`